# jQuery mobile form submit is reloading instead of loading new page

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a simple form, it only asks for the user's name which appears 'first' on my jQuery mobile app, the idea is that they'll enter their username (then authenticate for further use using cookies, or session), then be shown the 'main' page of the app. As of right now, when I attempt to enter my name into the form, the 'index' page appears momentarily, then the form just reloads back on top. I don't understand why this is happening, any help appreciated.

js:

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#introform', function(){  
        $(document).on('click', '#mysubmit', function() { // catch the form's submit event
            $.mobile.changePage("#index", {transition: "slidedown"});
        });    
});
```

html:

```
<body>


<div data-role="page" id="loginform">

<div data-role="content" id="nameof">


        <form id="username" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" method="POST" action="#index">  
            <fieldset style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="name" style="width: 100%; margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">what's your name?</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
                </div>
                <button id="mysubmit" data-theme="a" type="submit">submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

</div>
</div>


<div data-role="page" id="index">
   main body of app
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use #index to refer to, try a different name for

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
```

Perhaps

```
<div data-role="page" id="uniqueName">
```

And of course change the js:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#uniqueName", {transition: "slidedown"});
```

Edit: I just tried this, and it's actually the fact that jQuery mobile is storing the form still in the DOM, you have to remove it, so #index would in fact work fine if you added this line to your js:

```
$("#introform").remove();
```